# How to get the value form the has many in my view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models

pre_writing.rb

```
class PreWriting < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :students, optional: true
    belongs_to :classrooms, optional: true 
    belongs_to :options, optional: true  
end
```

student.rb

```
has_many :pre_writings
```

classroom.rb

```
has_many :pre_writings
has_many :classroom_students
```

in classroom/show.html.erb

```
 <% @classroom.students.each do |element| %>
  <% if @classroom.user_id == current_user.id %>
    <%= element.pre_writings.ids.first.updated_at %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

I get an error

```
undefined method `updated_at' for nil:NilClass
```

and if I try

```
<%= element.pre_writings.ids.first %>
```

I can get the id

and in console if I try

```
classroom.students.find(86).pre_writings.first.updated_at
```

I get the value

```
 Student Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" INNER JOIN "classroom_students" ON "students"."id" = "classroom_students"."student_id" WHERE "classroom_students"."classroom_id" = ? AND "students"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["classroom_id", 7], ["id", 86], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  PreWriting Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "pre_writings".* FROM "pre_writings" WHERE "pre_writings"."student_id" = ? ORDER BY "pre_writings"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["student_id", 86], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => Tue, 19 Dec 2017 23:50:52 UTC +00:00
```

Can someone tell me why I am getting undefined method error

Comment: What's the `ids` for?

Comment: because I tried <%= element.pre_writing.updated_at %> and I got an error

undefined method `pre_writing' for #<Student:0x007f9be0144f78>
Did you mean?  pre_writings
               pre_writings=
               pre_writing_id

Comment: `belongs_to` should be singular, not plural (e.g., `belongs_to :student`). You don't have `classroom.students`, you have `classroom.classroom_students` - which will be broken because you don't have a `ClassroomStudent` model. If you meant, `has_many :students`, then `Student` should `belong_to :classroom` and should have a `classroom_id` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that by using [.ids](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ids) you are returning an array of pre_writings ids and then with [`.first`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/first) you are selecting the first id and trying to access a not defined method (updated_at) for that id type (probably integer).
Also, when you are executing queries it is recommended to check if something is actually returned or the result set is empty. That is the case with the [`.first`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/first) ActiveRecord method and by checking if the query has returned results you are avoiding the `nil:NilClass access errors`.

What you might want to do is something like:

```
 <% @classroom.students.each do |element| %>
  <% if @classroom.user_id == current_user.id %>
    <% @first = element.pre_writings.first %>
    <% if @first.present? %>
      <%= @first.updated_at %>
    <% else %>
      - no record
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

**EDIT:**

You can also condense

```
    <% @first = element.pre_writings.first %>
    <% if @first.present? %>
      <%= @first.updated_at %>
    <% else %>
      - no record
    <% end %>
```

into

```
    <%= element.pre_writings.first&.updated_at || "no record" %>
```

The `&.` is called the [Safe Navigator syntax](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) that allows you to check for children attributes without having to do clumsy if-checks for existence of parents all the way down. This line will show the `updated_at` time, or if it's `nil`, will show `no record` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`element.pre_writings.ids.first` is an integer value and it doesnt have method `updated_at`
maybe you want to write `<%= element.pre_writings.first.updated_at %>`

Comment: if i try <%= element.pre_writings.first.updated_at %> 
I get undefined method `updated_at' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined method` error because the method is being called on nil.

You can only call `updated_at` on a `pre_writing`, so you need to make sure you have one first.

Then you need to call the method on the actual object rather than the id.

That can be done with something like
`<%= element.pre_writings.first.try(:updated_at) %>`

Using `try` will prevent the error if `pre_writings.first` is nil.

Or you can add the check in your if:

`<% if @classroom.user_id == current_user.id && element.pre_writings.any? %>
<%= element.pre_writings.first.updated_at %>`

You may also want to rename `element` to `student` for readability since it's the `student` that has many `pre_writings`.